# How to take column value count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

**Table1**

```
Column1
  20
  30
  40
  20
  40
  30
  30
```

I want take a count like this

```
20 - 2
30 - 3
40 - 2
```

In case if the column value 20 or 30 or 40 is not available, it should display `20 - 0` or `30 - 0` or `40 - 0`.

For example

```
Column1
20
30
20
30
30
```

Expected output

```
20 - 2 
30 - 3
40 - 0
```

I will get only 20, 30. 40.  No more value will come.

How to make a query

Need help

Comment: Have you tried using the `COUNT`  operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  item,count (item)  from table group by item
```

EDIT : ( after your edit)

```
 CREATE TABLE #table1       (          numbers int      ) 
insert into #table1 (numbers) select 20
insert into #table1 (numbers) select 30
insert into #table1 (numbers) select 40


SELECT [num]
  FROM [DavidCard].[dbo].[sssssss]

    select  numbers,count (num)  from #table1  LEFT JOIN [sssssss] ON #table1.numbers =  [sssssss].num      group by numbers
```

Comment: @Gopal , you also unchecked my answer , next time open a new question :)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Query 101:

```
SELECT Column1, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY Column1
```

**Update:** if you want to get a list of possible values, and their potential count (or 0) in another table, you need two tables, basically - one with all the possible values, one with the actual values - and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to put them together - something like:

```
SELECT
    p.Column1, ISNULL(COUNT(t.Column1), 0)
FROM    
    (SELECT 20 AS 'Column1'
     UNION 
     SELECT 30
     UNION 
     SELECT 40) AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.YourTable t ON t.Column1 = p.Column1
GROUP BY    
    p.Column1
ORDER BY 
    p.Column1
```

Comment: Your Query is working, For Example If 20 column is not there in the table means it should display 20 - 0,  How to do this

Comment: @GOpal: if "20" is not there - would should the query know there's supposed to be a "20 - 0" row there (and not a "21 - 0" or "25 - 0") ? You cannot do this - you can only count what's really there in your table ...